# Parse - Android - Will an exception be caused if no data is returned on a Parse query?

Tags: android, database, parse-platform

A quick question - would an exception be caused on a Parse query if no matches were found and no data was returned by the query?
 For example, I'm looking to query my username table to find out if a user/username already exists or not. So I'm wondering if no matches were found on a username then would that return an unsuccesful query with an exception or a successful query with no data in the list of objects?

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> userQuery = ParseUser.getQuery();
query.whereEqualTo("username", usernameInput);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

           @Override
           public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {

                   //query was successful
                   if (e == null) {

                   }

                   //query was unsuccessful
                   else {
                   }
}
```

Comment: semantically, the return value is a `List`, which should mean, unless indicated otherwise, that it return 0+ objects. It could return 0 object, or 23431 objects, both result would be valid. Finding no user with that name is not *exceptional behavior*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the code from [`ParseQuery`](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/blob/master/Parse/src/main/java/com/parse/ParseQuery.java):

```
public Task<List<T>> findInBackground() {
  return findAsync(builder.build());
}
```

you’ll eventually stumble upon [this](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/blob/bdd5f50d51d30030b9df12c0e09d08d8859e64be/Parse/src/main/java/com/parse/NetworkQueryController.java):

```
// Converts the JSONArray that represents the results of a find command to an
// ArrayList<ParseObject>.
/* package */ <T extends ParseObject> List<T> convertFindResponse(ParseQuery.State<T> state,
      JSONObject response) throws JSONException {
    ArrayList<T> answer = new ArrayList<>();
    JSONArray results = response.getJSONArray("results");
    if (results == null) {
      PLog.d(TAG, "null results in find response");
    } else {
      String resultClassName = response.optString("className", null);
      if (resultClassName == null) {
        resultClassName = state.className();
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); ++i) {
        JSONObject data = results.getJSONObject(i);
        T object = ParseObject.fromJSON(data, resultClassName, state.selectedKeys() == null);
        answer.add(object);

        /*
         * If there was a $relatedTo constraint on the query, then add any results to the list of
         * known objects in the relation for offline caching
         */
        ParseQuery.RelationConstraint relation =
            (ParseQuery.RelationConstraint) state.constraints().get("$relatedTo");
        if (relation != null) {
          relation.getRelation().addKnownObject(object);
        }
      }
    }

    return answer;
  }
```

Inspect the above - you can see that a successful query, even though it might contain no data, will still return a non-null `ArrayList` instance.